# Automatically stop and start a Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: scheduled-tasks, google-compute-engine

I'm using a `Google Compute Engine` instance for file synchronization. In order to save money I want the instance to be stopped overnight in my time zone. Is there any way to make the instance stop and start at particular times?

I know that I can send the stop and start commands to it using an `HTTP` request, but how would I send such a request at the right times if my own computers are not always 'on' at those times?

Answer (score 2):

This is not properly supported yet. You need to manually call start/stop commands (using HTTP, gcloud, etc.) from your own scheduler. You could take a look at google app engine, I think it should be possible to implement this kind of functionality there (if you don't have a spare machine to run cron jobs on).

Comment: Wouldn't setting up an app engine to schedule a compute engine defeat the purpose (of cutting costs)?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi, I was told that AppEngine has some free quotas for light use and the use of cron, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing. But I agree that this setup is way more convoluted that it should be.

Comment: you seem to be right, but it confuses me that compute engine costs money where app engine doesn't, because app engine would have to run on top of something like compute engine

Comment: As an update there are now  [Always Free Usage Limits on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits) that could be used to schedule the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

If you can send HTTP requests to turn on and turn off an instance, I would advise to use a standalone Google App Script from your Google Drive, that you can configure be executed every morning and every night through script triggers.

From [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) :

> To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the
>   script editor, follow these steps:
>
> 1. From the script editor, choose **Resources > Current project's
>      triggers**.
> 2. Click the link that says: **No triggers set up. Click here to add one
>      now.**
> 3. Under **Run**, select the name of function you want to trigger.
> 4. Under **Events**, select either **Time-driven** or the Google App that the
>      script is bound to (for example, **From spreadsheet**).
> 5. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for
>      example, an **Hour timer** that runs **Every hour** or an **On open** trigger).
> 6. Optionally, click **Notifications** to configure how and when you will
>      be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
> 7. Click **Save**.